# Optaplanner Drools rules error

Tags: drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I have the following Drools rule in Optaplanner:

```
rule "oneShiftPerDay"
when
    $leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftId : id, $employee : employee, $shiftDate : shiftDate, employee != null)
    $rightAssignment : ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDate == $shiftDate, id > $leftId)
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1); end
```

But when I run the solver I get the following error:

```
09:02:46.128 [main] ERROR o.d.c.k.b.impl.AbstractKieModule - Unable to build     KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase Error                      importing : 'be.comp.permanenties.domain.solver.EmployeeAssignmentTotal'
Error importing : 'be.comp.permanenties.domain.solver.EmployeeWorkSequence'
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='oneShiftPerDay']
        be/comp/permanenties/solver/Rule_oneShiftPerDay544009415.java (2:220) : Only a type can be imported. be.comp.permanenties.domain.solver.EmployeeWorkSequence resolves to a package
        be/comp/permanenties/solver/Rule_oneShiftPerDay544009415.java (2:978) : Only a type can be imported. be.comp.permanenties.domain.solver.EmployeeAssignmentTotal resolves to a package
```

How can I solve this error? Thanks.

Kind regards,

Nick

Comment: Duplicates [this mailing list question](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Optaplanner-rules-error-td4026047.html) which has an answer

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I had not yet seen that reply.

Comment: No problem :) If that's indeed what caused it, do copy paste an answer summary here for other optaplanner users that stumble upon this thread.

Answer (score -1):

It was a wrongly named import and consequently the imported package could not be found.

Comment: If you're not providing the actual fix this is not helpful at all.